# How to change a class attribute into an instance attribute Python Programming

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help changing the class atribute `size` to a instance attribute. 
This is the current code(which works):

```
class BoardHandler:
    size=None
    def __init__ (self):
        self.board = None

        if BoardHandler.size is None:
            self.ask_size()
        self.getNewBoard()

    def ask_size(self):  
        while True:
            try:
                BoardHandler.size = int(input("Which size would you want? "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Wrong! try again")
```

When I try changing the class into an instance attribute like this:

```
class BoardHandler:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.board = None
        self.size = self.ask_size()
        self.getNewBoard()

    def ask_size(self):  
        while True:
            try:
                self.size = int(input("Which size would you want? "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Wrong! try again")
```

So from now on, instead of calling onto `size` with BoardHandler.size I call on self.size. But the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users//Desktop/REVERSI/.py", line 281, in <module>
    menu()
  File "/Users//Desktop/REVERSI/.py", line 213, in meny
    main1v1() 
  File "/Users//Desktop/REVERSI/.py", line 236, in main1v1
    handler = BoardHandler()
  File "/Users//Desktop/REVERSI/.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.newBoard()
  File "/Users//Desktop/REVERSI/.py", line 50, in newBoard
    for i in range(self.size):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `ask_size` returns `None` . Either return an int or just call `ask_size`

Comment: you mean I would call `self.ask_size` instead of `self.size` ? @t.m.adam

Comment: I mean call `ask_size` but don't assign it to `size` or have `ask_size` return an int, like in @Daniel Sanchez's answer

Answer (score 2):

What happens is the following. With

```
    self.size = self.ask_size()
```

the method `ask_size` takes the user input, converts it to an `int`, and stores it in `self.size`.  The method then returns `None`, and that value is subsequently stored in `self.size`, as per the line quoted above. Net result: `self.size` contains `None`. Solution: either just call `self.ask_size()`, or modify `self.ask_size()` to return the size instead of setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine, the problem is that you are using `self.size` when it is still to `None`,return the value from the asking function instead of setting the `self.size`:

```
class BoardHandler:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.board = None
        self.size = self.ask_size()
        self.getNewBoard()

    def ask_size(self):  
        while True:
            try:
                size = int(input("Which size would you want? "))
                return size
            except ValueError:
                print("Wrong! try again")
```

Comment: Awesome, but how do I call on the value given from `size= int(input("size?"))` is it `self.size` or just `size` ?

Comment: @Entropy, the value will be returned and assigned to `self.size` on the `__init__` function, so it will be available from there.

Comment: The problem is that when I am running the program (which is a game called "reversi") somehow all the earlier tiles shuts down ending the game instantly

Comment: @Entropy, either you post all the code then or open another post, that shouldnt have to deal with this problem :(